# Database Connection unresponsive - Sybase

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling, sap-ase

I am trying to connect to a sybase ASE 15 enterprise edition database. Initially the connection is working fine but suddenly the page becomes unresponsive. There are no exceptions in the log nor is there any error displayed on the page. Also I have noticed that only the connection related to a particular database is unresponsive and remaining all are working just fine. However, if I restart the server, everything's working fine.

I have tried to increase the number of user connections and modified sytem configurations. But the result is all the same. Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you trace the session to get more log information:

```
 1- initiate a connection to the database
 2- use the stored procedure'sp_who' to identify the spid of the process of your connection on the server side
 3- set up the trace file for this spid:
 set tracefile 'log_file' for spid
(follow doc: http://www.sybase.com/files/White_Papers/ASE15-apptrace-070507-wp.pdf
 OR
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00743.1502/html/queryprocessing/BABJDBHJ.htm )
4- analyze your log file
```

let us know if it helped.

Comment: Hello Vince, 
I have executed sp_who and couldn't find any entry in the result that has the name of the database I intend to connect. Also, I don't have proper permissions to set up a trace file. Is anything amiss?

Comment: Perhaps you could ask your db administrator to follow the section "5.2-How to trace sessions of a specific login" in the doc http://www.sybase.com/files/White_Papers/ASE15-apptrace-070507-wp.pdf